# How to convert for each loop to for loop

Tags: java

I have a for each loop as under:

```java
for (Character character : string.toCharArray()) {
    stack.push(character);
}
```

Is there a way to convert this `for-each` loop into the usual `for` loop?

Comment: Your IDE likely offers to make that change.

Comment: By the way, `char`/`Character` has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Learn to use code point integer numbers instead, to work with individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

Sure,

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    stack.push((Character)chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: or use String::charAt

Comment: `String[] chars = string.toCharArray();` -> `char[] chars = string.toCharArray();`

Comment: Actually, use `int[] codePoints = myString.codePoints().toArray() ;`